# Use flutter_cache_manager with video_player

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

How can I stream a video using video_player and flutter_cache_manager?

All the examples I've seen download the file first using flutter_cache_manager and play the video after.

Thanks

Comment: As my understanding, streaming implies a active connection to the server. What are you trying to do? Cache for example 1 minute of a 10 min stream video?